# Change jquery-ajax to native JavaScript show 403: Error Forbidden

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am using yii framework for my php application. when i request `XMLHttpRequest();` it returns 403: Forbidden error. 
But the same code work fine when i use jquery-ajax method `$.ajax(attribute)`.

Is this is due to yii permission or any other reason.
Here is my native javascript code that seems to be fine.

```js
  ajaxHandler = {
    defaultAttributes: {
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'index.php/request',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {},
      success: null,
      error: function(data) {
        errorHandler.showError('An Error occurred while trying to retreive your requested data, Please try again...');
      },
      timeout: function() {
        errorHandler.showError('The request has been timed out, Please check your Internet connection and try again...');
      }
    },
    sendRequest: function(attributes) {
      Paper.giffyLoading.style.display = 'block';
      if (!attributes.nopopup) {
        if (attributes.loadmsg) {
          Controllers.AnimationController.createProgressBarScreen(attributes.loadmsg);
          attributes.loadmsg = null;
        }
      }
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open(attributes.type, attributes.url);
      xmlhttp.mimeTypes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
          console.log(jsonResponse);
          attributes.success(attributes.data);
        } else {
                console.log(xmlhttp);
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.send(attributes.data);
    }
  }
```

here is 'jquery-ajax code' working code in yii framework

```js
ajaxHandler = {
  defaultAttributes: {
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php/request',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: null,
    error: function(data) {
      errorHandler.showError('An Error occurred while trying to retreive your requested data, Please try again...');
    },
    timeout: function() {
      errorHandler.showError('The request has been timed out, Please check your Internet connection and try again...');
    }
  },
  sendRequest: function(attributes) {
    Paper.giffyLoading.style.display = 'block';
    if (!attributes.nopopup) {
      if (attributes.loadmsg) {
        Controllers.AnimationController.createProgressBarScreen(attributes.loadmsg);
        attributes.loadmsg = null;
      }
    }
    $.ajax(attributes);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know your jQuery version work? Seems there's no success callback. Also, the parameters are not exactly the same, you didn't specify mimeTypes for your jQuery call as well?

Comment: this is a default method i am defining sucess method, data and error message when i  send the request. i have tested the code as well